# Firebase query Stream with filters not updating when document is added: Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am working on the chat section of my flutter application. I have a **chat_messages** collection which contains all of the messages sent by users for all chats in the application. Below is the structure of a chat_messages document:

[image: A sample document from the chat_messages collection]

Here `user` is the sender of the message. I would like to display the number of unread messages (where the `message.seen==false`) for a specific user hence i used the query below to get a stram of all messages which where not seen by the user and i listen to that stream for any new messages sent:

```
    unreadMessagesStream = queryChatMessagesRecord(queryBuilder: (query) 
{
  return query
      .where('chat_users', arrayContains: currentUserReference)
      .where('user', isNotEqualTo: currentUserReference)
      .where('seen', isEqualTo: false);
});

unreadMessagesStream.listen((msgs) {
  if (mounted)
    setState(() {
      unreadMessagesCount = msgs?.length ?? 0;
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, this stream only produces a value once when the app is run, but later on when any new message is sent, new values are not received in the stream and the number of unread messages remain the same.

**NB: If I remove the filters and query the whole collection is works perfectly fine.**

Comment: I don't have that architecture. For me each users have a timestamp of the last time they read the chat and each message have a timestamp too. So just get the count of all timestamp messages that is greater than a specific timestamp user. It is more simple?

Comment: Your approach is quite interesting indeed

Answer (score 0):

I give you a snippet of my code to get it done faster: The code juste below is for each user. It's a subcollection of the chat. So a user could have a chatMembre for each chat.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

enum IsDoing { reading, notReading, writing, recording }

class ChatMembre {
  final String id;
  final DateTime lastReading;
  final DateTime lastReceived;
  final IsDoing isDoing;
  final bool hasSubscribeToTopic;

  ChatMembre(
      {required this.id,
      required this.lastReading,
      required this.lastReceived,
      required this.isDoing,
      required this.hasSubscribeToTopic});



  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'lastReading': lastReading == DateTime.now()
          ? FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
          : DateTime.now(),
      'lastReceived': lastReceived == DateTime.now()
          ? FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
          : DateTime.now(),
      'isDoing':
          isDoing.toString().substring(isDoing.toString().indexOf(".") + 1),
      'isSubscribeToTopic': hasSubscribeToTopic
    };
  }

  factory ChatMembre.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>? map) {
    if (map == null || map.isEmpty) {
      return ChatMembre(
          id: '',
          lastReading: DateTime.now(),
          lastReceived: DateTime.now(),
          hasSubscribeToTopic: false,
          isDoing: IsDoing.notReading);
    }

    IsDoing isDoing;

    switch (map["isDoing"]) {
      case "reading":
        isDoing = IsDoing.reading;
        break;
      case "writing":
        isDoing = IsDoing.writing;
        break;
      case "recording":
        isDoing = IsDoing.recording;
        break;
      default:
        isDoing = IsDoing.notReading;
        break;
    }

    return ChatMembre(
        id: (map['id'] ?? '') as String,
        lastReading:
            ((map['lastReading'] ?? Timestamp.now()) as Timestamp).toDate(),
        lastReceived:
            ((map['lastReceived'] ?? Timestamp.now()) as Timestamp).toDate(),
        isDoing: isDoing,
        hasSubscribeToTopic: (map['isSubscribeToTopic'] ?? false) as bool);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'ChatMembre{id: $id, lastReading: $lastReading, lastReceived: $lastReceived, isDoing: $isDoing, hasSubscribeToTopic: $hasSubscribeToTopic}';
  }
}
```

And under it's to look for the state of the chat page.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:customer/constants/credentials.dart';
import 'package:customer/constants/firestore_path.dart';
import 'package:customer/domain/repositories/my_chat_repository.dart';
import 'package:customer/services/firestore_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ChatRoomLifeCycle extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final MyChatRepository chatRepo;
  final String chatId;
  final String? token;
  final String? idTo;
  final Timestamp? lastReceivedOfFriend;

  const ChatRoomLifeCycle(
      {Key? key,
      required this.chatId,
      required this.chatRepo,
      required this.child,
      this.token,
      this.idTo,
      this.lastReceivedOfFriend})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatRoomLifeCycleState createState() => _ChatRoomLifeCycleState();
}

class _ChatRoomLifeCycleState extends State<ChatRoomLifeCycle>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  late GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey;
  bool hasSentFcm = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    sendPushMessage();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
    widget.chatRepo.setIsReading();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.chatRepo.setIsNotReading(isFromDispose: true);


    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        widget.chatRepo.setIsNotReading();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        widget.chatRepo.setIsReading();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        widget.chatRepo.setIsNotReading();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        widget.chatRepo.setIsNotReading();
        break;
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendPushMessage() async {
    if (hasSentFcm || widget.idTo == null || widget.token == null) {
      return;
    }
    FirestoreService.instance.updateData(
        path: MyPath.myUserStatus(uid: widget.idTo!), data: {'isLogin': false});

    try {
      await http
          .post(
            Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
            headers: <String, String>{
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'key=$serverToken',
            },
            body: constructFCMPayload(widget.token!),
          )
          .catchError((onError) {});

      hasSentFcm = true;
    } catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.toString());
    }
  }

  // Crude counter to make messages unique

  /// The API endpoint here accepts a raw FCM payload for demonstration purposes.
  String constructFCMPayload(String token) {
    return jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
      'data': <String, dynamic>{
        'test': 'check online',
        'chatId': widget.chatId,
        'idTo': widget.idTo
      },
      'to': token,
    });
  }
}
```